# How do I convince Linq to Sql to generate Sql to compare strings with greater than or less than?

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

Let's say I have a MS-SQL 2005 table named "People" with the following rows:

```
|FirstName|LastName|
|JD       |Conley  |
|Joe      |Schmo   |
|Mary     |Jane    |
```

I want to execute a SQL statement like:

```
select * from People where FirstName > 'JD'
```

The problem I'm having is I can't think of a way to get LINQ to SQL to generate this SQL statement. Obviously I can't use ">" and "<" operators on strings in C#.

Answer (score 3):

You want [`String.CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w.aspx) here

```
var query = from p in db.People
            where p.FirstName.CompareTo("JD") > 0
            select p;
```